# how to get last workitem in jBPM workflow?

Tags: jbpm

Requirement is jBPM workflow have 5 work items so once it reach 5th work item  and completed then how to get that work item is last ?

Comment: What is the intent of getting the work item?  Normally, a work item will set a result.  The result then can be mapped to a process variable which can be accessible by additional logic.  Basic steps are to: 1. create a process variable 2. place work item on process canvas 3. configure work item results to be assigned to process variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the audit logs. (Audit Logs -> using the ProcessEventListener to record all the nodes that were executed.